# How can I generate a PDF and load the contents of an ASCX asp.net user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET User control, .ascx and I need to generate a PDF with the contents of the user control. Is this possible, if so can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are many third-party PDF creation tools out there. One we've used at my work that works well is [PdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/)

As far as outputting the user control's as text, this is what you need to do:

```
        Page page = new Page();
        HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
        [USERCONTROL] uc  = (ReportHeaderInfoUC)page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/[NAME OF YOUR USER CONTROL].ascx");
        page.Controls.Add(form);
        form.Controls.Add(uc);
        //call the function on the user control that populates the control and pass in any data needed (if any)
        uc.Populate(data);
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        this.Server.Execute(page, stringWriter, false);
```

What you are basically doing here is creating a new WebForm, adding the user control to it and having the server render the output to a stream, which is basically what ASP.NET does for a regular page request.

To write the contents of the outputted user control to a file use:

> File.WriteAllText([FILE PATH], stringWriter.ToString());

Comment: How can I render the contents to an HTML file and save it on the server, instead of a PDF?

Comment: Did you end up implementing this answer?

Comment: Shai Cohen I did not understand, are you using PDFSharp on your example? Could you please elaborate it more? I'm having the same situation in which I need to "export" the contents of a usercontrol to a PDF file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the user control is only text based, it should not be difficult to output as a pdf with any pdf creation library out there (search for `generating pdf`, or `pdf creation`).  If your usercontrols have more complex html tags then you basically need to buy a Html 2 Pdf library.  I have not been able to find an acceptable free library that supports html to pdf.

You can also build up tables in PDF, but it would be very difficult to convert from html tables to pdf tables generically without buying a library to do that in my experience.  You could also code the building of the PDF tables separately from the usercontrol, but again very difficult to combine that function into it.